# Show all windows from a grouped program in the taskbar (Windows 11)

Tags: taskbar, windows-11

Since you can not ungroup items on the taskbar anymore in Windows 11 I'm looking for a way to show all windows of a single item/program on the desktop (e.g. "unminimize" them and bring them to the front).

There is a "half" solution: Turning on "Taskview" gives you a symbol on the taskbar that tiles all open windows on the desktop into a preview mode, but the individual windows are too small if you have many windows opened on a single monitor:

[image]

Is it possible to just do it for a single program? I know that the windows show when you hover over the item but this overview is quite small as well and to see the full window you have to hover over the thumbnails individually which is quite tedious. Right-click on the item on the taskbar only gives you the option to close all windows.

Several searches on the internet and on superuser didn't come up with any answers, at least not for Windows 11 (there are some similar questions for Windows 10).

Any ideas on how to solve this? I'm open to any suggestions and willing to try out a lot.

Apart from this question, an alternative solution would be to ungroup the taskbar items but I'm very unhappy with the solutions I found so far, [see my previous question here](https://superuser.com/questions/1708013/ungroup-taskbar-items-in-windows-11).

**Note:** There are a few 3rd party products to tweak the taskbar, but as far as I tried they couldn't restore the windows of a grouped item in the taskbar [Start11](https://www.stardock.com/products/start11/), [Open-Shell-Menu](https://github.com/Open-Shell/Open-Shell-Menu) or [StartAllBack](https://www.startallback.com/)

Comment: If unhappy with the Windows 11 taskbar, you could replace it by for example [Start11](https://www.stardock.com/products/start11/) (€6.99).

Comment: In that case, you could also try the older [Open-Shell-Menu](https://github.com/Open-Shell/Open-Shell-Menu), older but free. Is this worth an answer?

Comment: I have tried Open Shell and it works in Windows 11. Windows 11 is not that different from Windows 10.

Comment: Neither Start11 nor Open-Shell-Menu give you the option to show all windows (of at least one program) if the windows are minimized. Start11 gives you the option to e.g. cascade windows but this will not work for minimized windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't find a solution to show all grouped windows from a single item in the taskbar, but I managed two ungroup the item via a third-party software. In order to avoid redundant answers, I just linked to my main answer: [here](https://superuser.com/a/1713093/201818)

Note, this is just a workaround, my goal is still to show all windows from one grouped item.

Comment: Additionally you can "Ctrl + click" on the group and it will unminimize each one in left to right order